# GAE URLError trying to update files to the server

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Unknown error while trying to update my code to GAE server.

I tried to search something similar to this but google couldn't help me out on this.

I was able to update my code one or two days ago.

Below is the full error message.

```
$ appcfg.py update /dir/to/my/app
12:38 PM Host: appengine.google.com
12:38 PM Application: myappname; version: 1
12:38 PM 
Starting update of app: myappname, version: 1
12:38 PM Getting current resource limits.
2012-12-22 12:38:45,971 ERROR appcfg.py:2203 An error occurred processing file '': <urlopen error [Errno 0] _ssl.c:340: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)>. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/appcfg.py", line 171, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/appcfg.py", line 167, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4377, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4368, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2605, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4103, in __call__
    return method()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3115, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3097, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2173, in DoUpload
    self.resource_limits = GetResourceLimits(self.rpcserver, self.config)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 358, in GetResourceLimits
    resource_limits.update(GetRemoteResourceLimits(rpcserver, config))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 329, in GetRemoteResourceLimits
    version=config.version)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 391, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 394, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 412, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/__init__.py", line 383, in do_open
    raise url_error
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 0] _ssl.c:340: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)>
```

Comment: I was getting a similar error. There was no logical error message. Turns out my project was too big. Had to remove some files and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround that I found: delete the file google_appengine/lib/ cacerts/cacerts.txt from your installed SDK.

Still I don't know why and how,

so I'm leaving this question open.